# c# treeview path navigation

Tags: c#, treeview

I use Win forms treeview class. I need to have possibililty to navigate to specified node by its fullpath propety. i.e. I have fullpath ("country\region1\city2") and wish to select this node by this path automatically. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is treeview navigation by msdn

```
   private void PrintRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
       // Print the node.
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(treeNode.Text);
       MessageBox.Show(treeNode.Text);
       // Print each node recursively.
       foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
       {
          PrintRecursive(tn);
       }
    }

    // Call the procedure using the TreeView.
    private void CallRecursive(TreeView treeView)
    {
       // Print each node recursively.
       TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
       foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
       {
          PrintRecursive(n);
       }
    }
```

This could help you too
[codeproject variant of explorer with treeview navigation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/my_explorer.aspx)

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the specific question asked.